# getting error while using docker-compose build: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interpolate'

Tags: python, flask, dotenv

I am new to docker and while running `docker-compose build` command i am getting this error.

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                   
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())                                                                                      
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
    command()
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 125, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 76, in project_from_options
    environment_file=environment_file
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 135, in get_project
    config_data = config.load(config_details, compatibility, interpolate)
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 411, in load
    service_dicts = load_services(config_details, main_file, compatibility, interpolate=interpolate)
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 510, in load_services
    return build_services(service_config)
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 491, in build_services
    for name, service_dict in service_config.items()
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 491, in <listcomp>
    for name, service_dict in service_config.items()
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 483, in build_service
    interpolate
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 888, in finalize_service
    service_dict['environment'] = resolve_environment(service_dict, environment, interpolate)
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 687, in resolve_environment
    env.update(env_vars_from_file(env_file, interpolate))
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/config/environment.py", line 42, in env_vars_from_file
    env = dotenv.dotenv_values(dotenv_path=filename, encoding='utf-8-sig', interpolate=interpolate)
  File "/home/ghostface/playground/bootcamp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 283, in dotenv_values
    return DotEnv(f, verbose=verbose, **kwargs).dict()
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interpolate'
```

Result of `docker-compose version`

docker-compose version 1.26.0, build unknown
docker-py version: 4.2.1
CPython version: 3.6.8
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019

Requirement.txt file:

```
Flask==1.1.1          
Flask-Login==0.4.1             
Flask-Mail==0.9.1                
Flask-Migrate==2.5.2                   
Flask-Moment==0.9.0                
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0                 
Flask-WTF==0.14.2            
pusher==2.1.4            
PyJWT==1.7.1           
pylint==2.3.1               
python-dotenv==0.10.3                
Werkzeug==0.16.1                       
gunicorn       
docker-compose
```

Comment: Is this a docker-compose error or a container build error? It really seems like the latter, in whichever image is using the `python-dotenv` package.

Comment: @amiasato getting this error while building image.

Comment: It seems the error is raised because of the older version of `python-dotenv` library in the virtual environment - the [`interpolate`](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0110---2020-02-07) argument was added rather recently. Could you share some more info about the app, i.e. how the dependencies are listed? I would assume there is a file called `requirements.txt`. Then activating the virtual environment by `source venv/bin/activate` and then running `pip install -r requirements.txt` should help.

Comment: @NickShebanov thanx, this solved my problem,seems  `venv` folder was in different folder.

Comment: Glad to hear that! In any case, I've suggested a solution that you may want to use in the future should you have any problems with a similar setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your container uses a newer version of `python-dotenv` than the one that is listed in the `requirements.txt` file, as the [interpolate option](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/commit/a02bfac154e8a296f87372a0959f674aa622ebac) was added in [v0.11.0](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0110---2020-02-07).

You will need to change the version in `requirements.txt` to `0.11.0` (or the most recent one) and reinstall the dependencies.

It seems your container uses a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). You may need to check that the dependencies are correctly updated in the container, either by running `pip install` in the `Dockerfile`, or by running it locally beforehand.